# Kafka ReassignPartitionsCommand: IllegalArgumentException: long is not a value type

Tags: java, scala, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, illegalargumentexception

I'm trying to reassign partitions within my project and I'm getting this error.

```
    2017-08-22 15:57:28 DEBUG ZookeeperBackedAdoptionLogicImpl:320 - Calling ReassignPartitionsCommand with args:[--reassignment-json-file=partitions-to-move.json.1503417447767, --zookeeper=172.31.14.207:2181, --execute]
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: long is not a value type
    at joptsimple.internal.Reflection.findConverter(Reflection.java:66)
    at joptsimple.ArgumentAcceptingOptionSpec.ofType(ArgumentAcceptingOptionSpec.java:111)
    at kafka.admin.ReassignPartitionsCommand$ReassignPartitionsCommandOptions.<init>(ReassignPartitionsCommand.scala:301)
    at kafka.admin.ReassignPartitionsCommand$.validateAndParseArgs(ReassignPartitionsCommand.scala:236)
    at kafka.admin.ReassignPartitionsCommand$.main(ReassignPartitionsCommand.scala:34)
    at kafka.admin.ReassignPartitionsCommand.main(ReassignPartitionsCommand.scala)
    at rebalancer.core.ZookeeperBackedAdoptionLogicImpl.reassignPartitionToLocalBroker(ZookeeperBackedAdoptionLogicImpl.java:321)
    at rebalancer.core.ZookeeperBackedAdoptionLogicImpl.adoptRemotePartition(ZookeeperBackedAdoptionLogicImpl.java:267)
    at rebalancer.core.ZookeeperBackedAdoptionLogicImpl.run(ZookeeperBackedAdoptionLogicImpl.java:118)
```

I create the json file and use it as input to reassign partitions. I tried to use the same file with the builtin scripts of kafka and it is working.

```
kafka-reassign-partitions.bat --reassignment-json-file=partitions-to-move.json.1503417447767 --zookeeper=172.31.14.207:2181 --execute
```

I also tried to write a simple program with the same code to test the same file and it's working as well. This is happening for any json file and I reset the kafka environment before tests.

```
public class reassignPartition {
private static CuratorFramework client;
public static void main (String[] args) {
    client = CuratorFrameworkFactory.newClient(args[0] + ":2181", new ExponentialBackoffRetry(1000, 30));
    client.start();
    String reassignmentConfigFileName = args[1];
    String[] reassignCmdArgs = { "--reassignment-json-file=" + Paths.get(reassignmentConfigFileName),
            "--zookeeper=" + client.getZookeeperClient().getCurrentConnectionString(), "--execute" };
    System.out.println("Calling ReassignPartitionsCommand with args:{}"+ Arrays.toString(reassignCmdArgs));
    ReassignPartitionsCommand.main(reassignCmdArgs);
}
}
```

**What could be the problem?**

**Update:** Json Content

`{"partitions":[{"topic":"test1","partition":0,"replicas":[1]}],"version":1}`

Comment: print your json file content pls

Comment: @GuangshengZuo Added the json Content

Answer (score 0):

It was a version mismatch.. One of the pitfalls of working with different versions.
Kafka 0.10.2.0 uses jopt-simple-4.9.jar and Kafka 0.11.0.0 uses jopt-simple-5.0.4.jar